# How to create the common notification with ngx-bootstrap like toaster notification

Tags: angular, push-notification, angular2-services

I am new to angular 2& 4. I want to create the custom notification with ngx-bootstrap alerts and modal. I have searched and got some sample. But those are not simple. I just need a simple blueprint for create the notification with service,interface and component.

Please any one guide me with sample code.

Comment: Did you tried https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications ? AFAIK there are not toast notifications build in ngx-bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Official Documentation for `ngx-bootstrap` - [Alerts](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/alerts).
Official Documentation for `ngx-bootstrap` - [Modals](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals).
API documentation and usage scenarios available there with practical examples.

---

For quick reference, I'll give you the code for a simple Alert box - Usage and demo below:

First things first, Import the `ngx-bootstrap` in your Root module using:

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

---

Here goes HTML part `template`:

```
<alert type="success">
  <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</alert>
```

---

Code for `Component` given below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-alert-basic',
  templateUrl: './basic.html'
})
export class DemoAlertBasicComponent {}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you answered the same question twice instead of just consolidating your answers into one answer?

Answer (score 3):

> How to create the common notification with ngx-bootstrap like toaster notification

[Angular 2 Toasty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toasty) component shows growl-style alerts and messages for your application.
Online Demo available [here](http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/toasty).

---

- Just install it like any other npm package:
  `npm install ng2-toasty --save`
- If you're using SystemJS to load your files, update the config file:

  `System.config({
  map: {
      'ng2-toasty': 'node_modules/ng2-toasty/bundles/index.umd.js'
      }
  });`

Comment: yeah I know that. But it's need material package also. And I don't want to use that package.